# Extracting and reshaping inconsistent variable names

Tags: r

I have a long data frame (several hundred variables) that includes
a set experiments a, b, c that is repeated several times. The variables
names are standardized across experiments, but the names are not well standardized: for instance, the letter "a" appears at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the variable names, sometimes several time. I put a simplified example below:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(16, sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
names(df) <- c("var1", "var2",
           "varname_a_a",  "var_a_name", "varname_a", "a_varname", 
           "varname_b_b",  "var_b_name", "varname_b", "b_varname",
           "varname_c_c",  "var_c_name", "varname_c", "c_varname", 
           "var4", "var5")
```

Is there an efficient way to extract and reshape the experiments / data "blocks" a, b, c ("varname_a_a" to "c_varname") into a long format?

Thank you so much in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: To go from wide to long you can use `reshape2::melt`. It's not clear to me what your `id.vars` are though. Also, are you trying to "merge" cases like "a_varname" and "var_a_name"?

Comment: Maybe you give us an example of what result should look like?

Comment: `library(data.table); DT = melt(setDT(df), measure.var = patterns("varname_\\w_\\w", "var_\\w_name", "varname_\\w$", "\\w_varname"))`. You can use the `value.name` argument to give names to the four derived columns. You'll have to fill in the `variable` column with the letters like `DT[, variable := c("a", "b", "c")[variable]]`